# c++ loop wrongly jumped out on centOS7?

Tags: c++, loops, centos, gdb

i have a project that works well on ubuntu after compiling, the snippet is like:

```
void Backtest::start() 
{

    std::cout << "start  !!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << bars.size()<< std::endl;

    int jj=0;
    while(jj<bars.size()){
        std::cout << "on bar " << jj<<std::endl;
        newBar(&bars[jj]);
        jj++;
    }
}
```

on ubuntu everything works well, bars size is around 3020, but on centOS 7 it terminates at only jj =3, gdb output:

```
(gdb) next
start !!
3020
407     count = 0;
(gdb) 
408     jj=0;
(gdb) 
409     while(jj<bars.size()){
(gdb) 
410 std::cout << "on bar " << jj<<std::endl;
(gdb) 
on bar 0
411         newBar(&bars[jj]);
(gdb) 
412         jj++;
(gdb) 
409     while(jj<bars.size()){
(gdb) 
410 std::cout << "on bar " << jj<<std::endl;
(gdb) 
on bar 1
411         newBar(&bars[jj]);
(gdb) 
412         jj++;
(gdb) 
409     while(jj<bars.size()){
(gdb) 
410 std::cout << "on bar " << jj<<std::endl;
(gdb) 
on bar 2
411         newBar(&bars[jj]);
(gdb) 
412         jj++;
(gdb) 
409     while(jj<bars.size()){
(gdb) 
410 std::cout << "on bar " << jj<<std::endl;
(gdb) 
on bar 3
411         newBar(&bars[jj]);
(gdb) 
asd
|100000.000000,100000.000000|
get cash 100000.0
412         jj++;
(gdb) 
409     while(jj<bars.size()){
(gdb) 
415 }
```

at gdb 409 it weirdly gives empty loop and terminates, what is possibly wrong here???

```
void Backtest::newBar(Bar* b)
{
    if(Number == count+1){
        tempbars.push_back(*b);
        crossLimitOrder();
        strategyPy->onBar(tempbars);
        tempbars.clear();
        count = 0;
    }else{
        tempbars.push_back(*b);
        count ++;
    }        
}
```

PS newBar is something else in the project, it basically is calling a strategyPy to do something, and that will call a boost python module to call C++ function(which gives some API to python, including getCash(), thats why it prints out in debug info)

Comment: What is `newBar()`?  Also if that function is a non-static member, that `Backtest` instance better be valid.

Comment: Do you have another thread running? Where is "get cash" coming from?

Comment: just updated newBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be interesting to print the value of `jj` just after `get cash`.

My crystal ball says that it would have a very large positive or negative value, in which case your problem is stack buffer overflow somewhere in `newBar`, or one of the functions it calls.

Building your program with [Address Sanitzer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (`g++ -fsanitize=address ...`) should point you straight at the problem.

**Update:**

> i print the value of jj just after get cash but it says its still 3

You have to realize that

- there is no magic (either `jj` is not really 3, or your compiler is broken (very unlikely))
- debugging is a skill

What is possibly happening is that GDB prints only the lower 32 bits of `jj`, but the compiler uses entire 64-bit register (assuming 64-bit machine) to perform the comparison (and expects the high bits to all be 0). And something in `newBar` sets the high bits of `jj` to non-zero value.

Now, you can debug this in one of several ways:

- use `disas` command, find the actual `cmp` instruction, examine registers at time of comparison, or
- change the type of `jj` from `int` to `size_t` (at least GDB will then not perform any truncation), or
- run under Address Sanitizer (as already suggested).

Comment: i  print the value of jj just after get cash but it says its still 3